# How to assign .* as a value to variable in bash

Tags: bash, variable

When I am assigning .* to a variable , it is assigning all hidden files.

```
[root@s1 ~]# a=".*"
[root@s1 ~]# echo $a
. .. .bash_history .bash_logout .bash_profile .bashrc .cache .config .cshrc .history .lesshst .mozilla .pki .rnd .ssh .tcshrc .viminfo .virsh .xauth6SHzeY .xauthhAVYfm .xauthI6Cte3 .xauthk7ea35 .xauthlXtiZ9 .Xauthority .xauthQm7mJ8 .xauthTpWbxP .xauthY9KsdC
```

I expect below output :

> .*

How to escape it, thanks.

I tried below and it gives output

```
 [root@s1 ~]# a='".*"'
    [root@s1 ~]# echo $a
    ".*"
```

> ".*"

but not

> .*

Comment: I don't get why people downvote this. These problems are very common when you start using bash, everyone here had these. And research is difficult with terms like that and when you don't know the exact problem.

Comment: thanks you all, please let me know if it is worth accepting and  leaving the question active, or better to delete it.

Comment: marking it as duplicate should be fine, you can leave it open. Like that people can more search terms to find the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong in your assignment of the string `.*` to the variable, but since you use the variable unquoted with `echo`, the shell will perform (word splitting and) filename generation (globbing) on its value before calling `echo`.

To prevent this, double quote the variable expansion:

```
echo "$a"
```

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 6):

Since you need to call:

```
echo ".*"
```

in order to not get this expanded, you of course also need to call:

```
a=".*"
echo "$a"
```